# how to print a value in array with json

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$qr=mysql_query("SELECT `setting-name`,`setting-explain` FROM `fndn_Setting`");
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);
    for($i=1;$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);$i++){
        $arr[$i]=$row;
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Hi

the json print this value:

```
{"1":{"setting-name":"sms_num","setting-explain":"201300"},"2":{"setting-name":"sms_txt","setting-explain":"40"}}
```

But I want to print this value:

```
{"1":{"sms_num","201300"},"2":{"sms_txt","40"}}
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Why you don't reformat the array to your wishes that you echo instead of returning the query result?

Comment: `$arr[$i]=array($row['setting-name'] => $row['setting-explain']);`

Comment: Please dont use mysql_* it has been deprecated. it will get your question multiple down votes. other than that your way of retrieving data is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change one line to take only values

```
    $arr[$i]=array_values($row);
```